# Can't communicate correctly across 2 nodes through overlay network

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

### Hi everyone,

I'm discovering Docker Swarm and I'm struggling to deploy services in an overlay network (and make it work).
I'm using `docker stack deploy -c config.yml studio` with this **simple** compose file

```
version: "3.4"
services:
  redis:
    image: redis
  db:
    image: postgres
networks:
  default:
    attachable: true
    driver: overlay
    internal: false
```

The services are well deployed across my 2 nodes (1 service on each node), but the weird thing starts now.
I run `watch -n 1 docker network inspect studio_default` on the manager to have real-time status of my network, and I noticed that in the `Peers` field, the worker node appears and disappears randomly, so the service deployed on the node is *"randomly available/reachable"*.
Why the node disconnects itself from the network (and reconnects) ?

I can ping from the manager container to the worker one when the node appears in the `Peers`, but I think I can't even ping from the worker to the manager...

I'm lost

Answer (score 0):

You should ensure that ports 2377/tcp, 7946/tcp, 7946/udp, and 4789/udp are open between your nodes. See [Open protocols and ports between the hosts](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/#open-protocols-and-ports-between-the-hosts).